# How to select rows where a date is within range of another date column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, subset

I have a sample dataframe named df below

```
subj_id    admission_id    chart_date    admission_date     procedure
9          145834          2010-10-21    2010-10-23         surgery
14         122917          2010-05-30    2010-06-10         surgery
22         205461          2010-06-01    2010-06-15         surgery
31         237766          2010-03-05    2010-03-08         surgery
49         241908          2010-04-21    2010-04-21         CT-scan 
56         317751          2010-09-10    2010-09-25         surgery
67         382211          2010-08-05    2010-08-06         surgery
```

I'd like to just select the rows where the chart_date is more than 2 days after the admission_date but less than 14 days after the admission_date, where the result should look like this

```
subj_id    admission_id    chart_date    admission_date     procedure
9          145834          2010-10-21    2010-10-23         surgery
14         122917          2010-05-30    2010-06-10         surgery
22         205461          2010-06-01    2010-06-15         surgery
31         237766          2010-03-05    2010-03-08         surgery
```

I've tried the following code below but it returns me with empty rows. Was wondering if there is something wrong i am doing, appreciate any form of help. Thank you.

```
start <-df$admission_date + 2
end <-df$admission_date + 14

dfinclusion <- df[df$chart_date > start  & df$chart_date < end,]
```

Comment: It should work, maybe your dates are not in adte format ? Try using `ymd()` from lubridate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do subtract the values between `admission_date` and `chart_date` and select rows which are between 2 and 14 day period.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with('date')), as.Date) %>%
  filter(between(admission_date - chart_date, 2, 14))

#  subj_id admission_id chart_date admission_date procedure
#1       9       145834 2010-10-21     2010-10-23   surgery
#2      14       122917 2010-05-30     2010-06-10   surgery
#3      22       205461 2010-06-01     2010-06-15   surgery
#4      31       237766 2010-03-05     2010-03-08   surgery
```

---

Similarly, in base R :

```
df[3:4] <- lapply(df[3:4], as.Date)

subset(transform(df, diff_Date = admission_date - chart_date), 
                     diff_Date >=2 & diff_Date <= 14)
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(subj_id = c(9L, 14L, 22L, 31L, 49L, 56L, 67L), 
admission_id = c(145834L, 122917L, 205461L, 237766L, 241908L, 
317751L, 382211L), chart_date = structure(c(14903, 14759, 
14761, 14673, 14720, 14862, 14826), class = "Date"), 
admission_date = structure(c(14905,14770, 14775, 14676, 14720, 14877, 14827), 
class = "Date"), procedure = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
.Label = c("CT-scan", "surgery"), class = "factor")), 
row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```